# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable, though I am just passing a list to a function as an argument (Python)

Tags: python, function, class, decorator, python-decorators

I am currently programming a framework which uses strongly connected classes and runs specific function based on command names.

While writing a function which just passes a list and a function into another list, I ran into this issue:

```
File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    framework.module("modules.banner", console)
  File "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Framework\framework\framework.py", line 53, in module
    new = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Framework\modules\banner.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Banner:
  File "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Framework\modules\banner.py", line 41, in Banner
    event.commands(exit_console, commands)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The script which calls this function:

```
...
class Banner:
...
    @event.event
    def on_ready():
        self.banner()
    
    def exit_console():
        print("\033[1;32;0m")
        quit()

    command_names = ["exit", "quit", "e", "q"]
    event.commands(exit_console, command_names)
...
```

The event.commands function:

```
...
class event:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []
        self.commands = []
        self.parsers = []

    def event(self, function):
        self.events.append(function)
    def command(self, function):
        self.commands.append([function.__name__, function])
    def commands(self, function, lt):
        for name in lt:
            self.commands.append([name, function])
...
```

The difference between command and commands is that command takes one command name and commands take multiple.

Example for event.command:

```
...
@event.command
    def ping(args):
        print(args)
...
```

Thanks in advance, I have been looking into a lot of forums but could not find anything.

Comment: Instance attributes (`self.commands` defined in `__init__`) take precedence over class attributes (the method named `commands`). Pick a different name for one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `event` class, you defined `commands` as a list, and a function. That is causing the error.

```
class event:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []
        self.commands = [] #list here
        self.parsers = []

    def event(self, function):
        self.events.append(function)
    def command(self, function):
        self.commands.append([function.__name__, function])
    def commands(self, function, lt): #function here
        for name in lt:
            self.commands.append([name, function])
```